# Binary Tree Insertion Pointer Issue

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-tree

I have two functions in a class that creates a binary tree:

```
void Btree::insertNode(node* r, node* newNode){
    if (r == NULL)
        r = newNode;
    else if (greater(root, newNode))
        insertNode(r->left, newNode);
    else
        insertNode(r->right, newNode);
}

void Btree::load(){
    for (int i = 0; i < mainVec.size(); ++i){
        node* n = new node;
        n->index = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < mainVec[i].size(); ++j)
            n->s += mainVec[i][j];
        insertNode(root, n);
    }
    printTree(root);
    return;
}
```

I'd like load to fill up the tree at root (root is a private node pointer `node* root`), but every time insertNode exits root is still a null pointer.  Could someone point out my stupid mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make parameter `r` passed as a reference to be able to change `root` from inside the function `insertNode`.

See the below:

```
void Btree::insertNode(node*& r, node* newNode) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass root by reference.